# Dao pattern Java and Hibernate

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to create a good pattern for my application. I want to reduce as much as possible the duplicate code and I want to use generics as much as possible. I have created a pattern for this but I want to know is there anything wrong with the code or  if is there any other better pattern already made for this.

BaseDao interface:

```
public interface BaseDao<T extends DTO> {

    List<T> fetchAll();

}
```

BaseImplementetion: all the DAO classes will extend this class.

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends DTO> implements BaseDao {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public BaseDaoImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;

    }

    @Override
    public List<T> fetchAll() {

    List<T> entities = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = doOpenSession();
        Query<T> query = session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName());
        entities = query.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return entities;
    }
```

UserDao interface:

```
public interface UserDao extends BaseDao{
    User getUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDao implementation:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao{

    public UserDaoImpl() {
    this(User.class);
    }
    private UserDaoImpl(Class<User> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(String name) {

    User user = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        String hql = "FROM User u WHERE u.username = :name";
        Query<User> query = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(1);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        user = query.uniqueResult();
    }
    return user;
    }
}
```

PS: So, I want to create all the basic operations (add, save, update, getAll etc) in my BaseDaoImpl and after that all the DAO classes to inherit the class.

Do you think this approach can bring me problems latter?

Comment: The real question is: why you think you're gonna need it?

Comment: @CarmineIngaldi So, you say it is better to write in every DaoImpl class methods for save, update, getAll etc? I thought it is better to write them once and use them anywhere I want.

Comment: If you just want to provide API to do some generic CRUD operation on entities, you should implement a repository pattern, but only if you really need to reuse it across your codebase (let's say that you would write three times the same code) otherwise hibernate's DAO abstraction would be already enough for yor purpose. But if you need to implement your repository, i suggest you to take inspiration from JPA, for instance passing the generic type of ID along with type of entity

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is wrong în my approach?